# How can I create a borderless application in Python (windows)?

Tags: python, borderless

I would like to know how to create an application in Windows that does not have the default border; particularly the title bar with minimize, maximize, and close buttons.
I'm thinking of writing a ticker program that takes up a narrow space at the top or bottom of the screen, but I won't attempt it unless it's possible to make a thin application in Python. Any help with terminology is appreciated; maybe I don't know how to ask the right question in searching. Does Tkinter have this option?
Thanks

Comment: You could look into the WX module

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found an example that answered my question [here](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/657699-tkinter-tkmessagebox-overrideredirect). `overrideredirect(1)` is the key function.

I like this method because I'm familiar with Tk and preferred a Tk solution, but see the other answers for alternate solutions.

```
import tkMessageBox
from Tkinter import *

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.overrideredirect(1)
        self.frame = Frame(self.root, width=320, height=200,
                           borderwidth=2, relief=RAISED)
        self.frame.pack_propagate(False)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.bQuit = Button(self.frame, text="Quit",
                            command=self.root.quit)
        self.bQuit.pack(pady=20)
        self.bHello = Button(self.frame, text="Hello",
                             command=self.hello)
        self.bHello.pack(pady=20)

    def hello(self):
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Popup", "Hello!")

app = App()
app.root.mainloop()
```

Just need to add your own kill button or quit method.

Answer (score 8):

If you're willing to use [Qt/PySide](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QMainWindow.html), take a look at `QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint`  The code below just proves it's possible and doesn't try to be terribly useful.  In particular, you will have to force kill the app to get the app to close.  In a proper implementation, you would handle mouse events in a custom way to allow the user to move and close the application.  To run this, you will need to install [PySide](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Category:LanguageBindings::PySide::Downloads).

### Hacked up Code

```
import sys

from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)  
MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow(parent=None, flags=QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

MainFrame = QtGui.QFrame(MainWindow)
MainWindow.setCentralWidget(MainFrame)
MainFrameLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(MainFrame)

label = QtGui.QLabel('A Label')
MainFrameLayout.addWidget(label)

MainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've only used Tkinter in the past and just found an example that answers my question with Tk, but I'll read up on Qt and PySide and install it.

Comment: Feel free to take the answer that you put in your question, add it as an answer and then accept it as the answer since it best fits what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for providing a concise and simple example - works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Try Using QT Designer and Python (PyQT4)

and this code

```
from TestUI import Ui_MainWindow
class testQT4(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):    

        super(testQT4, self).__init__(parent,Qt.CustomizeWindowHint)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = testQT4()
    myapp.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

TestUI is your UI file
Created by using "cmd" going into your project directory (by cd[space][your path here])

and typing this

```
pyuic4 resfile.ui -o TestUI.py
```

above will create the TestUI.py on projects folder

resfile.ui is the file that you made on QT Designer

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've only used Tkinter so far. Is Qt recommended over Tk?

Comment: it depends on your needs. on my part QT and PyQT4 gives me all the flexibility i need in my program. and is easy on my level of programming