# Is there a way to paint/manipulate_pixels on the live PC screen using python?

Tags: python, c++, windows, image, opencv

I'm looking for a way to produce the output of my program in a way that the output appears on the live screen (output is typically a color filled shape) instead of appearing on a new window like it does for most Python programs.

I've attached an example of what I'm trying to achieve where only a part of the screen had its colors inverted (and will remain so as long as the script runs) and the rest remained as it is. NOTE:I've made the example using Photoshop.

I've tried PIL,OpenCV, Mss,curses.....but all these modules produce an output on a separate window.

Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible? If not with Python is it possible with C++? or is this something beyond the abilities of a programming language and needs to be done at the Operating System level itself?

[An example illustration of what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZG22P.jpg)

Comment: what do you mean by `live screen`? You can certainly reproduce that kind of effect with OpenCV as long as it lives inside a program window. However, if you want it for all running programs, then I would bet it's OS level.

Comment: This is not really a question about image processing, it's really about creating frameless windows and controlling the window manager. This is entirely possible, but the details depend on your WM and desktop framework.

Comment: @gavinb what kind of details? It's a standard windows 10 machine. And how can I go about creating frameless windows and control the window manager as you said?

Comment: Depends on which GUI library you're using, but here's a good start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371663/how-can-i-create-a-borderless-application-in-python-windows This will allow you to create a frameless window. It sounds like you want to have your app content on top, so look up the 'topmost' window flag.