# Python OpenCV - How to removing window border and title

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to 1) create a frameless window and 2) be able to resize the window to original or a set width/height

I've tried the fullscreen setting but only get a fullsized window.
[Python OpenCV - remove title bar, toolbar, and status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49095446/python-opencv-remove-title-bar-toolbar-and-status-bar)

```
videoFile = "./videos/screen_sav1_lr2.mp4"
videoWindowName = "VideoWindow"
playbackRate = 30

videoCapture = cv2.VideoCapture(videoFile)
if not videoCapture.isOpened():
    print("Error: Could not open video.")
    exit()

cv2.namedWindow(videoWindowName, cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
cv2.setWindowProperty(videoWindowName, cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
```

I've also tried

```
cv2.namedWindow(videoWindowName, flags=cv2.WINDOW_GUI_NORMAL)
```

How do I maintain the original size or resize it as borderless?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenCV doesn't provide this functionality, you'll have to use some other GUI frameworks. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371663/how-can-i-create-a-borderless-application-in-python-windows)'s a thread with few options

Comment: Thanks again.  This posting was helpful.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31085533/how-to-remove-just-the-window-border